# Unexpected box of color in UITableViewCell When Setting Background Color

Tags: ios, uitableview

Sometimes an unexpected box of color shows up in a UITableViewCell.

[image: Screenshot from iPhone 5]

The following method ultimately gets called by tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func indicateAsDoneCell(cell: ButtDTaskListTableViewCell) {

    if let itemName = cell.item?.name {

        var attrs = [NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName : 1]
        cell.textLabel?.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(itemName)", attributes: attrs)
        cell.contentView.alpha = 0.5
        cell.backgroundColor = self.allTasksAreDone() ? UIColor.yellowColor() : UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    }
}
```

In Interface Builder, clip subviews is on for both the cell and content view. It's a Basic Style cell. It happens in iOS 7 and iOS 8.

What also may be related is that done items are moved/animated to the bottom when selected.

When I scroll the cells with the unexpected light-gray box off the screen and scroll it back onto the screen, I still see the unexpected light-gray box.

If I comment out the line that sets the cell's background, I sometimes get this.

[image: unexpected box showing up]

Any idea as to what is going on with the light-gray box showing up in some of the Done items / cells?

---

Additional Code as requested.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : ButtDTaskListTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as ButtDTaskListTableViewCell;

    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let sortedByDoneStatus = !tableView.editing // self.sortByDoneStatus

    let item : ButtDTaskItem = taskManager.objectInListAtIndex(indexPath.row, sortedByDoneStatus:sortedByDoneStatus)
    cell.item = item

    indicateDoneStatusOnCell(cell, inEditMode:tableView.editing) // !tableView.editing

    return cell;
}

func indicateDoneStatusOnCell(cell : ButtDTaskListTableViewCell, inEditMode:Bool) {

    if let existingItem = cell.item? {

        if (!inEditMode && existingItem.isDone) {
            indicateAsDoneCell(cell)
        } else {
            indicateAsNotDoneCell(cell)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: one trick that I've used in the past is to give every interesting UI element a different color, red, green, yellow etc... This way they aren't all white and you can see WHICH element is showing where you don't expect it.

Comment: also, there is a willDisplayCell delegate for table view.  Setting final colors here may help.  Not sure if this is the issue here, but can try.

Comment: The tips from PaulCezanne (playing with the colors) and @ort11 (where to set the color) both helped.  I got the box to go away by setting in Interface Builder: 1) a "Default" background color on the Table View, 2) a "Default" background color on the Cell, 3) a Clear Color on the Content View, and 4) a "Default" background color on the Label. The data source no longer sets the background color nor changes the alpha. The willDisplayCell method sets the appropriate backgroundColor on the cell. There is a refresh issue. However, let's call that a separate thing. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the box to go away by setting the following in Interface Builder:

- a "Default" background color on the Table View
- a "Default" background color on the Cell
- a "Clear Color" on the Content View
- a "Default" background color on the Label.

The data source no longer sets the background color nor changes the alpha. The willDisplayCell method sets the appropriate backgroundColor on the cell.

Comment: Great help from @ort11, paul-cezanne, and salavat-khanov :) Thanks all!